# Syntax error when deploying Rails app to Heroku: ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected character

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, coffeescript

I am trying to deploy my app to Heroku but its throwing me this error.

> "ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected character '`' (line:
>   14577, col: 33, pos: 440811"

I assume there is something wrong with the coffeescript/javascript. I have deleted all of my coffeescript files and I dont know what I'm doing wrong.

As suggested by Iceman, ive tried running the command

> rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development

and it says

> I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.173928 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing >/Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/circle->cb2239e32deac2eba5c693c3574b562595f1f933a8896866e47c170bf87c77e4.png
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.209986 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing >/Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/fb->e361b3ecca9c24c6c05646b170fe25fcc185fa2eafb7aa46780253c8a9c79a04.png
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.225079 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing >/Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/los->f083228761f6ede67e04a1a73906b4585bc5cfd3154ffec4861c4f04cf95aa32.jpg
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.253212 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing >/Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/main->221235002689ad3847a67a05ce3608ebed4ee709be6fcf61bc0ccef2001b487f.jpg
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.272155 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/us-background-638489d758e08327ad62f883f11397bc870df84038b502ea17c3e2510cac6ef4.jpg
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.313969 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/zaisan-5f83c22eef3372c96199aad34ab9ad1744d6124e845a01267fcabcec39e2e948.jpg
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.426829 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/application-cadb51eb7487d2788eae31912fc18cc28ffaf8d48ea022d2a8a49c121415d7f8.js
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.427380 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/application-cadb51eb7487d2788eae31912fc18cc28ffaf8d48ea022d2a8a49c121415d7f8.js.gz
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.540537 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/application-8b6461ded0e51f6232fa5606fc47c47cd9b64684fbbeccd9fed16d7a0a66deee.css
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.540807 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/application-8b6461ded0e51f6232fa5606fc47c47cd9b64684fbbeccd9fed16d7a0a66deee.css.gz
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.543684 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-7bfcab6db99d5cfbf1705ca0536ddc78585432cc5fa41bbd7ad0f009033b2979.eot
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.597933 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-7bfcab6db99d5cfbf1705ca0536ddc78585432cc5fa41bbd7ad0f009033b2979.eot.gz
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.601098 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-2adefcbc041e7d18fcf2d417879dc5a09997aa64d675b7a3c4b6ce33da13f3fe.woff2
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.638449 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-ba0c59deb5450f5cb41b3f93609ee2d0d995415877ddfa223e8a8a7533474f07.woff
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.675384 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-aa58f33f239a0fb02f5c7a6c45c043d7a9ac9a093335806694ecd6d4edc0d6a8.ttf
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.716776 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-aa58f33f239a0fb02f5c7a6c45c043d7a9ac9a093335806694ecd6d4edc0d6a8.ttf.gz
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.721169 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-ad6157926c1622ba4e1d03d478f1541368524bfc46f51e42fe0d945f7ef323e4.svg
>   I, [2017-01-26T16:32:25.808396 #2674]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/Gana/Documents/bombay/bombaydarbar/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-ad6157926c1622ba4e1d03d478f1541368524bfc46f51e42fe0d945f7ef323e4.svg.gz

is there something wrong with my image files?

Comment: Without seeing any code it is rather hard to help I'm afraid.

Comment: I dont know which part to show, everything seems to be working perfectly fine on my local server until i try to deploy it

Comment: You could try doing `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development` on your local server, it might give a better clue where the error is.

Comment: THanks, i have tried doing the command i could not understand it, i've edited the post can you take a look at it again please

Comment: There are no errors in the snippet you posted, you must be getting some errors when you precompile.

Comment: oh, it was because my javascript files were in .js format i bundle installed sprocket gem and changed all the .js files to .es6

Comment: Addition to answer from Ali Haris.
You can fix the uglifier error using *harmony: true*
But it’s not the best solution for production as you need babel to cast es6 to es5.

Answer (score 15):

The problem, as some of the users has mentioned, is Rails JS uglifier not being able to handle ES6 template literals.

Uglifier now has a Harmony mode which supports ES6 / ES2015+ syntax.

You can enable it by passing `:harmony => true` option to Uglifier.

Open `config/environments/production.rb`

Replace

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

with

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm facing a similar error, it seems like Rails JS uglifier can't handle [ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). You might need to replace "`" (template literals) with single or double quotes.
In case you want to verify, copy paste your problematic JS (you'll have to search for "`" in your JS directory) file here https://jscompress.com/ and see the error.